# Magento 1.x: Is it possible to rewrite classes in website level?

Tags: magento-1.7, overrides, magento-1, websites

I need to rewrite some classes per website level in Magento 1.x. Is it possible?

Basically looking some way as If website is "A" then rewrite this class & its method. But if website is "B" then don't do anything.

**As for layout control per website we can do this** & if we disable mymodule from backend per website my layout will not be visible.

```
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <mymodule module="Akhil_Mymodule">
                <file>mymodule.xml</file>
            </mymodule>
        </updates>
    </layout>
```

Like same way can we do something for rewrite also?

Comment: you can check a website condition in class.

Comment: Yes but need something like "If website is "A" then rewrite this class & its method. But if website is "B" then don't do anything."

Comment: Added more description.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you cannot rewrite classes at website level, because classes (as entities) are website agnostic.
But you can use some tricks like this.

Let's say that you need to rewrite a method called `doSomething` the class `A` for website w1 only.
Rewrite the class, and make the `doSomething` method look like this:

```
class B extends A 
{
    public function doSomething()
    {
        $website = Mage::app()->getWebsite();  
        if ($website->getCode() != 'w1') {
             return parent::doSomething();
        }
        //your awesome code here
    }   
}
```

Comment: Thanks..! I had also module conflict-ion issue (Three modules A,B,C(in local codepool)). So instead  parent i used the classname of model for my third module C. It's working as expected.