# How to scope class overwrite to affect only within module?

Tags: magento-1.8, overrides

When I overwrite a Model/Controller/Helper overwrite through `<rewrite/>` in my module, how can I do it such that the overriding of the classes is scoped within my module and those that declares `<depends/>` on my module?

So let's say I have `moduleA`, `moduleB` and `moduleC`.

I did a rewrite of `Mage_Core_Catalog_Product` and called it `My_Test_Catalog_Product` in `moduleA`.

`moduleB` `<depends/>` on `moduleB` in its module config file. So, I would like only `moduleA` and `moduleB` to have that rewrite effect. In other words, only `moduleA` and `moduleB` will read from `My_Test_Catalog_Product` while `moduleC` will remain status quo (reading from `Mage_Core_Catalog_Product`).

Currently, it seems like the effect of overwriting a core Model or Controller from my module is global in Magento.

Comment: Yes, class rewrites are global. I don't know, what you mean with "module scope" in this case, but here is a similar question: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/114540/magento-1-x-is-it-possible-to-rewrite-classes-in-website-level - but maybe there is a different solution to your problem, so if you update the question with some information on what you are trying to achieve and why you might get an answer.

Comment: @fschmengler I've updated my question to elaborate on what I meant by module scope. Thanks!